# Get first letter of a String (more than one word)

Tags: java, string, char, tostring

I am trying to get the first letter of every word in a String:

```
String recInf = recursos.getString(nombre);

char[] tipoAbreviado = recInf.toCharArray();
tipoAbreviado[0] = Character.toUpperCase(tipoAbreviado[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < recInf.length() - 2; i++) {
    // Es 'palabra'
    if (tipoAbreviado[i] == ' ' || tipoAbreviado[i] == '.' || tipoAbreviado[i] == ',') {
        // Reemplazamos
        tipoAbreviado[i + 1] = Character.toUpperCase(tipoAbreviado[i + 1]); 
    }

    nombre = tipoAbreviado.toString();
}
```

Finally the value of `nombre` is [C@3b1938ea, not the first letter of every word in `recInf`

Comment: Use static method `Arrays.toString(tipoAbreviado)` instead of `tipoAbreviado.toString()`. The array's `toString` method don't create  "understandable" `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.toSting(your_array)` to print your `Array`.

Take a look what `toString()` in `Arrays` do

```
 public static String toString(long[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
        return "[]";

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        b.append(a[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
            return b.append(']').toString();
        b.append(", ");
    }
}
```

But when you use `tipoAbreviado.toString();` it will call `toString()` method in `Object` class.

What `toString()` method in `Object` class do?

```
 public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

That's why you are getting your current out put.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `toString` on an `Array` which `prints the memory address representation`, you should create a `String` from `char[]` using [new String(char[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[]))

```
nombre = new String(tipoAbreviado);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string's `.split()` with the correct regex and then just pick the first char:

```
 String[] words = "Your String & !+ and some extraodrinary others".split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
 for (String word: words ){
    System.out.println(word.charAt(0));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the String object you want to process is `recInf` i would recommend to do it as follows:

```
String recInf = new String(text.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Nd} ]+"," ")
    .replaceAll("[\\s]+", " "));
String[] words = recInf.split(" ");
String[] firstLetters = new String[words.length];

for(int i=0; i<words.length;i++){
   firstLetters[i]=words[i].getCharAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch them with a Regular Expression.

When I use the RegEx `(\w)\w+` on the string `Hallo Welt, ich bin ein String`, I get an array with `H, W, i, b, e, S`. Note: You have to run the expression as global expression (more than once).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
nombre = (new StringBuilder(tipoAbreviado)).toString();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: "Finally the value of nombre is [C@3b1938ea, not the first letter of every word in recInf" I found this sentence as the question, so I offered a solution to it. In a short form...